# Не выполняется метод после выполнения AsyncTask

Tags: android, sqlite, android-asynctask

Не могу понять, где ошибка, прошу подсказать:
Есть метод, который должен выполниться после завершения работы другого потока, но после выполнения работы потока, метод просто не обрабатывается.  тот же самый код, но при работе в основном потоке отрабатывается нормально. код ниже:
метод, который выполняется в другом потоке

```
public List<example> loadData() {
    //List<example> list = myApplication.getDb().getmylist();// метод выполнения в основном потоке
    myApplication.getDb().getmylistAsync(new DataBaseHelper.DatabaseHand<List<example>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(boolean success, List<example> result) {
            if (success) {
                listSecond.addAll(result);
            }
        }
    });
    return listSecond;
}
```

`listSecond` у меня возвращается `null` и выпадает `NPE`
метод `loadData` вызывается в `onResume`:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    values = loadData();
    if (values != null && values.size() > 0)
        MiddleTabAdapter adapter = new MiddleTabAdapter(getActivity(), values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

методы выполняющие работу в классе с бд:

```
@Override
public List<example> getmylist() {
    List<example> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String selectQuery =
        "SELECT * FROM " + list_applicationsTable +
        " WHERE " + status_Request + " = 0";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Example example = new Example();
            example.set_id(cursor.getInt(0));
            example.add(example);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public void getmylistAsync(DatabaseHand<List<Example>> handler) {
    new DatabaseAsyncTask<List<Example>>(handler) {
        @Override
        protected List<Example> executeMethod() {
            return getmylist();
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

Comment: Приведите нормальный кусок кода где видно что и где вызывается, а не отрывки из разных частей. Лично мне ваш код непонятен.

Comment: @temq добавил код

Comment: 1 - Вы точно хотите в методе ```executeMethod``` вызывать снова ```getmylistAsync```. 2 - Кажется что ```myApplication.getDb().close()``` вызывается рано в случае с ```getmylistAsync```, т.к. база может закрыться раньше чем завершится работа с ней. Остальное вроде бы выглядит нормально.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При запуске какой то работы в другом потоке, поток который это запускает не дожидается окончания второго потока, а продолжает выполнение.

`NPE` вылетает из-за того что `listSecond` не инициализирован(равен `null`). Но если бы он у вас был инициализирован например пустым списком, то метод `loadData` с асинхронной реализаций все равно бы возвращал пустой список т.к. поток, который запускается в методе `getmylistAsync` просто не успел бы добавить туда данных до момента завершения метода `loadData`.

Comment: как тогда исправить можно? повесить ожидание выполнения второго потока?

Comment: @Сергей блокировать поток не надо, иначе какой смысл от второго потока? Делайте то что вам надо в ```onComplete```, только если вы будете трогать UI то следите что вы это делаете в UI потоке.